# IIS Account Interact With Windows UI

Tags: user-interface, selenium-webdriver, iis

We have some automation code that runs on a server, uses selenium and headless chrome to do some testing/work. We have a system that doesn't work with Chrome, only with IE, and we need to utilize the same system. However, we ran into the issue where IE doesn't work in any type of headless mode. It all works when I run it locally via IIS because it's authenticating as me (and I can see the UI)

Is there a way we can have an IIS process, on a server, use a normal domain/user account that would allow it to physically/visually run the UI and be able to automate IE? We see the process actually starts Internet Explorer on the server but the automation stops there because it can't do anything with IE. I can navigate, just can't interact with anything on the DOM.

I already know lots of reasons of why we *shouldn't* do this. Right now I'm just in need of a quick-fix. I plan to persuade our team that we should redesign the entire approach but, for now, there is a fire that needs to be extinguished faster than we can rewrite the system... :/

Thanks for any tips,
Will

Comment: It is not obvious to me why you want to automate IE , but Microsoft didn't design IE in that way. You might write some code around the `WebBrowser` control (like the one in .NET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=net-5.0) which executes upon the same IE core. That allows you to touch on DOM easily (but that's not yet the real IE in many ways). I don't think there is any "quick fix".

Comment: Can't get into specifics but we basically have a really old system with no API behind it and so much red tape that there could not be one in less than 12 months. Meanwhile, we have a specific set of actions that we have to do thousands of times a day and instead of having employees do that work, we can do it via automation. Well, in Chrome we can, but apparently not with this IE-based system that uses a lot of ActiveX objects...

Working on a windows EXE that can do it locally if I can automate it directly on the server.